# Is there a problem initializing a JAXBContext with a package in a library?

Tags: java, jaxb, package

I'm trying to initialize a JAXBContext like so:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents");
```

When the code is run, however, I get the following run time error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ebay/apis/eblbasecomponents/ObjectFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents.ObjectFactory
```

The ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents package is in a library that the initialization code has access to. The ObjectFactory class IS in that package. I actuall ran it like this to make sure:

```
    ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents.ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    factory.createAddressType();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents");
```

I'm not an experienced Java developer, so I'm not even really sure what might be the problem at this point, other than it can't seem to find a class that is obviously there. I have done a clean and build on the library that has the package in question, and that works just fine. I thought I would ask for help on here while I continue poking around trying to figure this out.

Comment: Maybe the files are not in your build path? Are you using an IDE - which one?

Comment: What do you mean by 'in a library'? In a jar file in your classpath?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans. By "in a library" I mean created a Global Library in Netbeans that contained a jar that had the package in question (along with a few others) and added this to my project. I can access all the classes in this library through code just fine as I noted above. I should probably point out that I'm a .NET developer who was told to learn Java (and I'm the only person with any (not much) Java experience here).

Comment: I think the main problem here is that I didn't understand how Java classpaths work exactly - I assumed they were more like references in C# in that they could be nested, which they can't. Whatever the main project is it needs to have all code being used on it's classpath, even if it's on a class library's classpath already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, well I moved the package out of the library it was in and directly into the project that was trying to access it (so it can access the package directly instead of having to do it through the library) and it seems to be working now. Hopefully someone will have a better answer or solution explaining why this is, but for now at least the project isn't blowing up on me.